# Basic d3 tooltip/styling - graphic being offset

Tags: css, d3.js, tooltip

I've just started experimenting with d3.js, and have been trying to add functioning tooltips.  I should note that I've also never worked with tooltips before this experimentation.  I'm under the impression that this should be a fairly simple question to answer:

When I mouse over one of my targets, the div into which I placed the tooltip (above my graphic) goes from a height of 0px to however much space is needed to display the text (or a specified height).  I was under the impression that if the position was relative, the div effectively moved.  This is problematic because it pushes my page down by whatever height it needs whenever a tooltip is displayed, which is pretty disruptive.

You can see exactly what's happening here:  http://jsfiddle.net/76analytics/u6tnyqgc/14/

As an aside, I was also wondering why putting that div below my graphic disabled the tooltip altogether.

```
<title>D3 Graphic </title>
<body>
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>D3 Graphic </h2>
        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You probably want to absolute position the tooltip div, see [this tutorial](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-tooltips-to-d3js-graph.html).

Comment: Oh, thanks.  That worked.  It wasn't moving at all until I made it relative, so I figured that was what I had to do.  Thanks!